Issue while installing Ubuntu 22.04 in external SSD
Currently using Windows 10, also wanted to use Ubuntu 22.04.1 but without dual booting, so thought to install Ubuntu on external SSD (SA100 SATA 2.5").
But after several process I can't detect my external SSD, while installing whenever I reached to that point, I don't able to select for that external drive...
Help is needed!!!
First created a flash pendrive then tried to install Ubuntu on external SSD but couldn't selected the external SSD.
Second I have done the same thing instead of pendrive, to external SSD.

Often the install tools create a hybrid DVD/flash drive configuration that does not have standard partitions. What format is external drive? Is it gpt partitioned? Does gparted see it from live installer flash drive? Post this: sudo gparted -l in question above.
